# Get filename in datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using the Get Metada activity and I need to get the filename from the activity output:

**Output Actitity**

```
Output
{
    "childItems": [
        {
            "name": "FILENAME.mdb",
            "type": "File"
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "xxxxx",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 5
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: If you think my answer help you,you could mark it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0].name
```

My test pipeline:

[image]

Output of 'Set variable1':

[image]